# How to format a date to remove the time?

Tags: c#

Simple question but simple work-arounds don't seem to be working for me. At the moment in my model I have this:

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DebitDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
  @foreach (var i in Model.ReportData) {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@i.TypeID</td>
                                        <td>@i.CPAttached</td>
                                        <td>@i.ReviewName</td>
                                        <td>@i.ClaimID</td>
                                        <td>@i.Line</td>
                                        <td>@i.AccountNo</td>
                                        <td>@i.SupplierName</td>
                                        <td>@String.Format("{0:C0}", i.Amount)</td>
                                        <td>@i.StatusCategoryDesc</td>
                                        <td>@i.DateSent</td>
                                        <td>@i.DayOS</td>
                                        @if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault() == 1) {
                                            <td>@i.NominalPeriod</td>
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            <td>@i.SLInvoiceNo</td>
                                        }
                                        <td>@i.Area</td>
                                        <td>@i.DebitRef</td>
                                        <td>@i.DebitDate</td>
                                        <td>@i.DeductDate</td> 
                                        <td>@i.APLReason</td>
                                        @if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault() == 1) {
                                            <td>@i.DeptNo</td>
                                            <td>@i.DeptName</td>
                                        }
                                    </tr>
```

But this doesnt work.

Does anybody have any quick work arounds?

View or model, either will do.

Comment: can you make `DateTime?` to `string`?In that case you can format the data after you retrieve from db or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
<td>@i.DebitDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DebitDate { get; set; }
```

This only works when automatically generating your model `@Html.ModelFor`, but in your case your are generating it manually using `foreach`